# Getting and Display Records from API

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to get list of tracks related to an album and i am having problem displaying the records using my API. How can i get to display all the tracks under an album and it will give me the Track ID, Track Title etc.

```
<ul class="tracklist">
    <li class='tracklistRow' v-for="album in albums">    
        <div class='trackCount'>
            <img class='play' src='/assets/images/icons/play-white.png' onclick='playSong()'>
            <img class='pause' src='/assets/images/icons/pause.png' style='display:none;' onclick='pauseSong()'>
            <span class='trackNumber'>{{ album.track.id }}</span>
        </div>                      
            <div class='trackInfo'>
                <span class='trackName'>{{ album.track.track.title }}</span>
            </div>  
        <div class='trackOptions'>
            <img class='optionsButton' src='/assets/images/icons/more.png'>
        </div>

        <div class='trackDuration'>
            <span class='duration'>{{ album.track.track.duration }}</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <div class="rLabel" v-if="album">
        &copy; {{ album.albumDetails.recordlabel }}
    </div>
</ul>
```

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        name: 'album',

        props:['id'],
        data: function(){
            return {
                album: null,
                albums: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getData(){
                var that = this
                axios.get('http://api.localhost/api/album/'+this.id)
                    .then(function (response){
                        that.album = response.data.data;
                    })

            }
        },
        mounted: function(){
            this.getData()
        }
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Your `album` in the `v-for` shadows `this.album`, which is filled by an api call, while simultaniously `this.albums` is kept empty (causing the `v-for` to never loop). It simply sounds like you are trying two different approaches at the same time, but didn't work out either one.

Comment: @Sumurai8 i have done this ```v-for="track in album.track.track"``` but i am getting this error ```[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'track' of null"```